# if, elseif not setting variables to set correct variable

Tags: php, if-statement

I cant seem to figure out why this is not working correctly.  Here are the variables being set, however in the end result of "type" it sets it to m and not fm

cpanel_notifications - 1
remote_server - 1

```
if ($_POST['cpanel_notifications'] == 1){
$type = "m";
}
elseif($_POST['cpanel_notifications'] == 0){
$type = "nm";
}
elseif($_POST['cpanel_notifications'] == 1 && $_POST['remote_server'] == 1){
$type = "fm";
}
elseif($_POST['cpanel_notifications'] == 0 && $_POST['remote_server'] == 0){
$type = "fnm";
}
```

Result: m

Comment: the first condition is always evaluated to true

Comment: The first condition is true, so the rest of the else conditions are not checked

Comment: @Alon exactly .... else part doenot make any sense if condition in if is always true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need todo is reorder your if's

```
if($_POST['cpanel_notifications'] == 1 && $_POST['remote_server'] == 1){
    $type = "fm";
}
elseif($_POST['cpanel_notifications'] == 0 && $_POST['remote_server'] == 0){
    $type = "fnm";
}
elseif ($_POST['cpanel_notifications'] == 1){
    $type = "m";
}
elseif($_POST['cpanel_notifications'] == 0){
    $type = "nm";
}
```

Comment: had to set the second elseif to 1 for remote_server but that worked.  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This is because the first `if` statement is true. There is no reason to go to any of the `elses`.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the conditions order

```
if ($_POST['cpanel_notifications'] == 1){
    if ($_POST['remote_server'] == 1) { 
        $type = "fm";
    } else {
        $type = "m";
    }
}
elseif($_POST['cpanel_notifications'] == 0){
    if ($_POST['remote_server'] == 0) {
        $type = "fnm";
    } else {
        $type = "nm";
    }
}
```

or even

```
if ($_POST['cpanel_notifications'] == 1){
    $type = ($_POST['remote_server'] == 1?"fm":"m");
}
elseif($_POST['cpanel_notifications'] == 0){
    $type = ($_POST['remote_server'] == 0?"fnm":"nm");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments specifying to move your statements with multiple conditions up higher. As a general rule of thumb, you want to put your most specific statements up top and get more generic as you go down the condition list.

Answer (score -1):

Add more =

```
if ($_POST['cpanel_notifications'] === 1){
$type = "m";
}
elseif($_POST['cpanel_notifications'] === 0){
$type = "nm";
}
elseif($_POST['cpanel_notifications'] === 1 && $_POST['remote_server'] === 1){
$type = "fm";
}
elseif($_POST['cpanel_notifications'] === 0 && $_POST['remote_server'] === 0){
$type = "fnm";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

The above link show you why adding the extra = sign.